# installing pymysql on windows ImportError: cannot import name FIELD_TYPE

Tags: python, windows, pymysql

I'm trying to setup **pymysql** for **python 3.3** on **windows 64 bit**.

I managed to install easy_install using **https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute#downloads** I did a **python distribute_setup.py** then **easy_install** started working.

Now whenever I try to do **easy_install pymysql** I get

```
Downloading/unpacking pymysql
  Downloading PyMySQL-0.5.tar.gz
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pymysql
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "c:\users\cc\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Cc\pymysql\setup.py", line 7, in <module>
        version_tuple = __import__('pymysql').VERSION
      File ".\pymysql\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
        from constants import FIELD_TYPE
    ImportError: cannot import name FIELD_TYPE
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "c:\users\cc\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Cc\pymysql\setup.py", line 7, in <module>

    version_tuple = __import__('pymysql').VERSION

  File ".\pymysql\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>

    from constants import FIELD_TYPE

ImportError: cannot import name FIELD_TYPE

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in c:\users\cc\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-Cc\pymysql
Storing complete log in C:\Users\Cc\pip\pip.log
```

Originally the error was 'could not import name 'constants'' then I ran easy_install constants and now the error is the one above.

**EDIT**
Upon closer look I saw they say for python 3.3 to do

```
echo "Building Python 3.0 version in ./py3k..."
rm -fr ./py3k
mkdir py3k
cp -rf pymysql py3k/
cp setup.py py3k/
cp setup.py.py3k.patch py3k/
cp CHANGELOG py3k/
cp README.rst py3k/
cp LICENSE py3k/
cd py3k
2to3 .|patch -p0
patch setup.py setup.py.py3k.patch
cd ..
```

Any idea how I can do this in Windows the command **2to3 .|patch -p0**

Comment: i had the same problem,On,linux, I went to https://code.google.com/p/pymysql/downloads/list
download the pymysql package and then  
$ python3 setup.py install --user

Answer (score 0):

I think you're installing the python2 version.

Try this instead:

easy_install pymysql3